# Using awk or sed how can i print between the pattern (same pattern) only when the text in the middle of the pattern matches

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

Using awk or sed how can i print between the pattern (same pattern) only when the text in the middle of the pattern matches
For example suppose file contains

```
# Wed 10/12/2015
field1=a
field2=b
field3=c
field4=d
# Wed 10/12/2015
field1=e
field2=f
field3=g
field4=h
# Wed 10/12/2015
field1=i
field2=j
field3=k
field4=l
```

i want the block between two '#' to be printed where field3=g
Below script i have written is not working

```
awk '$0 ~ /^#/{
       start_flag=1;
    }
    $0 ~ /g$/{
       mid_flag=1;
    }
    start_flag {
            n=NR;
            lines[NR];  
    }
    $0  ~ /^#/
    {
       if (start_flag && mid_flag)
       {
            for (i=n; i<NR; i++)
            print lines[i];
       }
       start_flag=0;
       mid_flag=0;
       delete lines
    }' <file_name>
```

Expected o/p is

```
field1=e
field2=f
field3=g
field4=h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS='#[^\n]*\n' -v ORS='' '/field3=g/' ip.txt 
field1=e
field2=f
field3=g
field4=h
```

- `-v RS='#[^\n]*\n'` set input record separator to be `#` upto and including next newline character
- `-v ORS=''` set output record separator to empty string
- `/field3=g/` print all records containing the text `field3=g`

@[NeronLeVelu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2885763/neronlevelu) suggests alternative to ensure `#` is matched at start of line

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)[[:blank:]]*#[^\n]*\n' '/field3=g/' ip.txt
```

Comment: maybe just add a starting`^` in RS in case the caret is in a field line content (just for securing because OP specify "*example suppose*", it doesn't change your very efficient solution)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu I checked, but `^` anchoring is matching only start of file...

Comment: right, it's at file/stream level, not record level, I try with a `(^|\n)[[:blank:]]*#[^\n]*\n`, seems working here

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `grep`

```
grep -A1 -B2 "field3=g" file
```

`-A` and `-B` options print NUM lines of trailing context after and before of matching line.

you get,

```
field1=e
field2=f
field3=g
field4=h
```

**Only for fun**

If, you want to print all the neighboring records to match `field3=g` using `sed`

```
sed -n '/^#/{
    :c; :a; n; H; 
    /^#/{bc}; 
    /field3=g/{x; s/.*#[^\n]*\n//;p;:d;n;/^#/{bc}; p; bd}; ba;
};:b' file
```

you get,

```
field1=e
field2=f
field3=g
field4=h
```

Or using `awk`

```
awk '
    /^#/{i=0; f=0} 
    {m[++i]=$0} 
    /field3=g/{for(j=2; j<=i; ++j) print m[j]; f=1; next}
    f' file
```

You get the same result

Comment: This may work if the number of fields between # are same i.e. 4 field, but in my case the number of fields are not the same in each block . sometimes 5 , sometimes 4 etc

Comment: I post another solution using `sed` with new requirements

Comment: I post another solution using `awk` with new requirements